# Is there a way to create a Tableau session via Python which will open a workbook and refresh extracts, then publish workbook to the server?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, extract, tableau-api

I am looking everywhere for this and not having much luck.  I am using Python 2.7 and Tableau 9.0.  If you(reader) know of any other viable options, I'm open to anything, but more proficient with Python.  Can anyone please give me direction as to where this can be found?  Or if it is even possible?

Thank you,
Phil

Comment: If you have Tableau Server, why not use a scheduled task to refresh the extract?

Answer (score 0):

Hi phill you can use tabcmd to achive this functionality.
here are list of commands: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm

1) tableau login

```
tabcmd login -s https://<YourServerName> -u <YourUsername> -p <YourPassword>
```

2)refresh

```
tabcmd refreshextracts --url "<workbook_name>"
```

3)To get local copy:

```
 Tabcmd get https://<YourServerName>/workbooks/workbook_name?format=twb&errfmt=html" -f "<new_name.twbx>"
```

4)Publish

```
tabcmd publish "<localpath>" -n "<new_name>"
```

It worked for me. Let me know if it helped you too.

Comment: Hi, I saw those commands for tabcmd, and managed to run them on the command line as well - but how do I run those command on a Python script? could you upload maybe a small example? it would be a big help. Thank You!!